# mesos slaves are not connecting with mesos masters

Tags: mesos

i have a setup where i am using two mesos masters and two mesos slasves. after making all the required configurations i can see two mesos masters are part of a cluster which is maintained by zookeepers and they are switching in a time interval. so i believe my mesos master config was successful.

now i have setup two mesos slaves and when i am starting mesos-slave service, i am expecting that mesos slaves will be available to the mesos masters web UI page. But i can  not see any of them in the slaves tab.

I have followed a document mentioned [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-production-ready-mesosphere-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04)

i am not sure what could go wrong. i have verified the ip addresses of masters and slaves and they are configured correctly.

i don't know which part need to be checked for trouble shooting.

Comment: I know it is an old question, but have you managed to solve this? I am facing a similar situation where one slave connects and the other one doesn't. Both are configured the same way. Right now, the second slave's "mesos-slave" process isn't even going up.

Comment: i reconfigured them and the issue was resolved. Make sure in your zookeeper configuration you have mentioned mesos-slaves properly. Also connectivity between master and slave systems are proper.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please verify that there is connectivity between slaves and the masters? It might be a good idea to take a look at master and slave logs to see what's going on.

Comment: yes connectivity between master and slaves are fine. i have tested with ssh connectivity and they are okay. so there exists no firewall issues.

Comment: Check what's in slave logs, also make sure that your slaves bind to the correct network interface, it always safer to use `--ip` option to ensure that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're setting up Mesos cluster on AWS or similar service, you might want to make sure that required ports are open. From the setup I did on AWS, I remember below ports but you might want to verify:

- Zookeeper - 2181
- Mesos Master - 5050
- Mesos Slave - 5051

You can use telnet from master to slave and vice-versa on above mentioned ports to make sure that firewall is not the issue. Also, make sure that quorum value is set properly.

> i have a setup where i am using two mesos masters and two mesos slasves.

It is recommended to have one or odd number of master nodes. You might want to add or reduce one master node. I can't find the link for this recommendation at the moment but I will add one once I find it.

> zookeepers and they are switching in a time interval

If they're switching at certain time intervals, chances are configuration is not correct. Leading master role is switched only when the existing leading master node is malfunctioning for some reason. Otherwise, this doesn't keep switching by itself.

Besides that, providing logs from master and slave nodes would be of help. Logs on my CentOS 7 system are at `/var/log/mesos/mesos-master.INFO` and `/var/log/mesos/mesos-slave.INFO` for master and slave nodes respectively. An excerpt from these files in your question would be helpful.

Comment: dharmit, if switching mesos master node is not natural then i have to fix this.

Comment: dharmit, unfortunately i dont have more than 4 systems, so i can not increase mesos masters. here is one thing that i have done to experiment on this. i have created one docker image with mesos installed in a ububtu based image. now i have created 3 mesos-master docker and 3 mesos-slave docker images running. good thing is here mesos-masater is not switching and i can see all 3 mesos-slaves connected to the master.

Comment: @psaha4 that's a good thing then! I have not deployed Mesos cluster in docker images. I referred [this guide](http://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/datacenter/install/) by the good folks at Mesosphere to set things up on CentOS 7 systems

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced scenarios that can cause this:

- Slave terminated soon after start. This happens sometimes after package upgrades or when VM resource changes (eg. you scaled up CPUs on your cloud instance). You'll see a log line in mesos-slave logs about this, telling you to remove a directory. Usually the solution is to remove `$WORK_DIR/meta`. If you don't need to recover any executors, you can just remove the whole WORK_DIR. Then start the mesos-slave.
- Slave can not connect to ZK to determine master. This can happen if you provide ZK entry for master discovery (you should, `/etc/mesos/zk`) instead of directly providing master options. Ensure mesos-slave -> zookeeper connectivity.
- Similar to above, `/etc/mesos/zk` entry (or at least the zookeeper node) are not identical across your cluster.
- Ensure mesos-master(s) <-> mesos-slave(s) connectivity